# Suggestions for optimizing length of bins for a time period

Tags: algorithm, optimization, genetic-algorithm, binning

I have an optimisation problem where I need to optimize the lengths of a fixed number of bins over a known period of time. The bins should contain minimal overlapping items with the same tag (see definition of items and tags later).

If the problem can be solved heuristically that is fine, the exact optimum is not important.

I was wondering if anybody had any suggestions as to approaches to try out for this or at had any ideas as to what the name of the problem would be.

### The problem

Lets say we have *n* number of items that have two attributes: *tag* and *time* range.

For an example we have the following items:

(tag: time range (s))

(1: 0, 2)

(1: 4, 5)

(1: 7, 8)

(1: 9, 15)

(2: 0, 5)

(2: 7,  11)

(2: 14, 20)

(3: 4,  6)

(3: 7,  11)

(4: 5,  15)

When plotted this would look as follows:

[image: Fig1]

Lets say we have to bin this 20 second period of time into 4 groups. We could do this by having 4 groups of length 5.

And would look something like this:

[image: Fig1]

The number of overlapping items with the same tag would be

Group 1: 1 (tag 1)

Group 2: 2 (tag 1 and tag 3)

Group 3: 2 (tag 2)

Group 4: 0

Total overlapping items: 5

Another grouping selection for 4 groups would then be of lengths 4, 3, 2 and 11 seconds.

[image: Fig1]

The number of overlapping items with the same tag would be :

Group 1: 0

Group 2: 0

Group 3: 0

Group 4: 1 (tag 2)

### Attempts to solve (brute force)

I can find the optimum solution by binning the whole period of time into small segments (say 1 seconds, for the above example there would be 20 bins).

I can then find all the integer compositions for the integer 20 that use 4 components. e.g.

This would provide 127 different compositions

(1, 1, 4, 14), (9, 5, 5, 1), (1, 4, 4, 11), (13, 3, 3, 1), (3, 4, 4, 9), (10, 5, 4, 1), (7, 6, 6, 1), (1, 3, 5, 11), (2, 4, 4, 10) ......

For (1, 1, 4, 14) the grouping would be 4 groups of 1, 1, 4 and 14 seconds.

I then find the composition with the best score (smallest number of overlapping tags).

The problem with this approach is that it can only be done on relatively small numbers as the number of compositions of an integer gets incredibly large when the size of the integer increases.

Therefore, if my data is 1000 seconds and I have to put bins of size 1 second the run time would be too long.

## Attempts to solve (heuristically)

I have tried using a genetic algorithm type approach.

Where chromosomes are a composition of lengths which are created randomly and genes are the individual lengths of each group. Due to the nature of the data I am struggling to do any meaningful crossover/mutations though.

Does anyone have any suggestions?